# How to update related cases and fields from one recordtype to other recordtype in lead

Tags: apex-code

```
public class UpdaterecordtypeforLead {
    Public static void Leadtootherupdate() {
     List<Lead> OlderLead = [SELECT Id,Name, RecordTypeId from Lead where RecordType.Name = 'Enquiries'];
    List<Lead> NewLead = New List<Lead> ();
    If(NewLead.Id == null)
    {
       for( Lead l : OlderLead) {
          for(Lead l1 : NewLead) {
               l1.LastName = l.LastName;
               l1.Email= l.Email;
               NewLead.add(l1);
               NewLead.add(l1);
              Insert l1;
          }
       }
    
    If ( (l1. LastName == l.LastName && l1.Email == l.Email)) 
    {
          NewLead.add(OlderLead.Related_Cases__c);
          NewLead.add(l.Id);
          Update NewLead;
   }
} 
     
    }
}
```

I'm getting error while saving.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a lot of issues:

- What is the context / aim of this code ?
- Query using `DeveloperName` not `Name` as it's language dependent
- Testing `if (NewLead.Id == null)` when ``NewLead` is a list will not work
- Looping on NewLead for what reason ?
- Duplicate `NewLead.add(l1)`
- Insert in a loop will gets you to governor limits and should be avoided, go for bulk insert
- The `if` is outside the loop
- Don't update something you just insert, instead make sure everything is okay before insert
- `NewLead` is a list of `Lead` so you can't add `OlderLead.Related_Cases__c` or `l.Id` to it
- Think about indenting correctly your code, it's easier for others to read
- Use naming conventions

A fixed code would probably be something like this:

```java
public class UpdateRecordtypeForLead {
    public static void leadToOtherUpdate () {
        List<Lead> olderLeads = [
            SELECT 
                Id,
                LastName,
                Email,
                RecordTypeId
            FROM 
                Lead 
            WHERE 
                RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Enquiries'
        ];
        List<Lead> newLeads = New List<Lead>();

        for (Lead olderLead : olderLeads) {
            newLeads.add(new Lead(
                Id = olderLead.Id,
                LastName = olderLead.LastName,
                Email = olderLead.Email,
                RecordTypeId = 'the_new_record_type_id'
            ));
          }
       }

       update newLeads;
   }
}
```